# 3-cnf-sat with a twist question

Tags: computer-science, np-complete, conjunctive-normal-form

If you change the 3-cnf-sat problem as follows:
For each c<sub>i</sub>, c<sub>i</sub> = -x<sub>i1</sub> OR -x<sub>i2</sub> OR x<sub>i3</sub> meaning exactly one of the variables appears without a negation.
You are also given values (0 or 1) to some (or all) of the x's.
You should be able to solve the problem (finding values of the x's that satisfy the problem or prove that it is unsatisfiable) in polynomial time.

1. What is a polynomial running time algorithm that solves this problem?
2. Prove that it runs in polynomial time.

*hint: show that c<sub>i</sub> = -x<sub>i1</sub> OR -x<sub>i2</sub> OR x<sub>i3</sub> is equal to c = (x<sub>i1</sub> AND -x<sub>i2</sub>) -> x<sub>i3</sub>*

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 1):

The formulas you describe are a subset of Horn formulas. The satisfiability problem is thus no harder than [Horn satisfiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HORNSAT) and admits the same linear-time solution.